# Give an example to show that the inequalities are strict inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

> Give an example to show that the following three inequalities $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} (a_n) +\liminf_{n \to \infty} (b_n)\le\liminf_{n \to \infty} (a_n+b_n)\le\limsup_{n \to \infty} (a_n+b_n) \le \limsup_{n \to \infty} (a_n) + \limsup_{n \to \infty}(b_n)$$ are all strict inequalities.

Can anyone please explain how I answer this question? I do not understand which example to give to satisfy the above or how I should go about it. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: By the way, the wording of the (quoted) question is horrible in my opinion. All inequalites are in fact *non-strict* – just as stated – because for $(a_n) = (b_n) = 0$, all terms are zero, so equality holds everywhere, meaning you can’t replace »$≤$« by »$<$« without rendering the general statement false. What they should have asked for is an example for which all inequalities are strict inequalities.

Comment: @k.stm that is what the question asked. They basically just asked to give an example where all the inequalities are strict inequalities

Comment: How about the wording: Give an example to show they are not equalities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll get you started.  Let $a_n=(-1)^n$ and $b_n=(-1)^{n+1}$.  Then $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n)=\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}(b_n)=-1$.  But $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n+b_n)=0$.

Note that you don't need the same sequences to satisfy all inequalities.

Comment: So basically, what you're saying is that we can have different sequences for the three different inequalities? If we wanted to have the same sequences to satisfy all of the inequalities what would we do?

Comment: The sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ that I gave work for the first and last inequalities, just not for the middle one.  A little tweaking can get sequences that work for all three.  I'll leave it to you to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Wait a minute here, who negged me?  That was just rude.

Comment: So basically i should pick an alternating sequence?

Comment: Yes.  Something like this.  Let $a_n$ be the sequence $-2,1,-2,1,-2,1,\dots$ and $b_n$ the sequence $1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,\dots$.
That should make all inequalities strict at the same time.  I get $-3<-1<0<2$ unless I made a mistake.

Comment: In this example, how can $a_n$ be expressed in a more compact form?

Comment: $a_n=\frac32(-1)^n-\frac12$.

Comment: If you want to express the answer with a formula like that, then you can find an easier example, where all terms involved in the formula are integers.